# How can I get facebook user's friends using facebook_sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully managed to facilitate facebook users to authenticate to my application using their facebook login by using facebook_sdk.

Now I want to get friends of the person who authenticated my application.

How can I achieve this with facebook_sdk?

Comment: Did you try to open https://graph.facebook.com/USERID_HERE/friends ? You need to add auth token to that url in query string. It returns json data.

Comment: It is asking me the access token ? It is looking like this when I click https://graph.facebook.com/1000022937570253/friends

Comment: You need to get oauth token for your app first. I will post you an example now.

Comment: You should probably just start at http://developers.facebook.com - there's decent documentation and the SDKs come with sample code

Comment: Yeah I tried and I am getting facebook user profile data but I want also to get his friends name.

Comment: I am getting access token by calling $user = $facebook->getUser();
$userAccessToken=$facebook->getUserAccessToken();
$accessToken=$facebook->getAccessToken();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is jsfiddle showing how you can get list of friends from js:
http://jsfiddle.net/R3KF4/2/

Just place your app id and secret at the bottom, and id of fb profile which has authorized that app.

I suggest you to turn on network tab / capture in developer tools in your browser, so you can see what goes over the wire.

It is based on my simple feed getter:
https://github.com/goranobradovic/CommonCodeSnippets/blob/master/JS/fbUtils.js

Of course, to properly secure your application, you need to perform first step (get oauth token) from server side code (in php). To be clear, you need to place your app id and secret into this url: `"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={appId}&client_secret={secret}"` and then perform get request from php to acquire token, and then place it into js as variable, so users opening your page do not see your app id and secret. From js you can then use `'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ userId + '/friends&' + token` to load json with friends.

Comment: Now I have the friends but I it is funny file that is hard to display in normal view! So how can I handle it

Comment: Well, it is depending on what you want to show? Maybe you could use knockoutjs for that? There is sample currently on homepage of my domain: http://goranobradovic.com/ which loads json with blog posts and displays it using html template. If you take a look at the html source and http://goranobradovic.com/Scripts/Home.js it should be clear to you.

Comment: Of course, if you just want to show items, you could use jquery templates: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl as knockout is more suited for building rich interface with a lot of interactions.